# How to make a Hp value in a console game?

Tags: c#

ok so im pretty new to programming and am trying to make a game where i roll random ints for the dice inside of a loop and i want to be able to subtract the results of the dice roll from a value for the enemy's Hp and have that value carry over throughout the loop until the hp value equals zero then break the loop and end the game. I have tried declaring an int for the value, but i cant figure out how to save the damage dealt from the previous dice roll loop. Can anyone point me in the right direction to do this?

Edit:
forgot to add the code whoops.
This is my crappy code

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          
                Program.hit();
            
        }

        static void hit()
        {
            bool enemyAlive = true;
            while (enemyAlive)
            {

                

            Random rnd = new Random();
            int roll20 = rnd.Next(1, 21);
            int roll6 = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int rollCrt = rnd.Next(1, 7);
            int critDmg = roll6 + rollCrt + 4;

            if (roll20 == 20)
            {
                WriteLine($"\nyou rolled. { roll20} CRIT!!");
                WriteLine($"you deal.  {roll6} + {rollCrt} + 4 = {critDmg} damage.");
                //currentEhp = enemyHp - critDmg;
                   // WriteLine(currentEhp);
                
            }
            else if (roll20 <= 14)
            {
                WriteLine($"\nyou rolled. {roll20} you miss");
            }
            
            else if (roll20 >= 15)
            {
                WriteLine($"\nyou rolled. {roll20} you hit");
                WriteLine($"you deal. {roll6} damage");
                    //currentEhp = enemyHp - roll6;

                   // WriteLine(currentEhp);
            }

                ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should show the section of code that's giving you trouble, and explain what it's doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare the int variable outside of the loop and subtract from within the loop.

For example:

```
int hp = 100;

// I'm guessing this is the dice roll loop
for (int i = 0; i < NumOfTimes; i++)
{
   if (hp <= 0)
       break;
   
   DiceRoll();

   hp -= ValueOfDiceRoll;
}
```

Comment: wow it was that simple thanks